# How to avoid flickering or blinking when change the language of datatable?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am using bootstrap datatable to display my data. After i included the language function to my datatable then i can see there's flickering when first load the page.

```
  "language": {
             "url": '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/English.json'
            },
```

It's just like rendering the table and very noticeable, how can i avoid this situation?

Comment: You code is rather incomplete. Have you followed the example? See: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/language_file.html

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, no problem for my code, just the flickering is annoying.

Comment: I think your problem will remain unsolved unless you give an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You could make a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ran into this same issue. Changing the url to a local one instead of going to the cdn did not solve it either. Were you able to solve it?